# Recaptcha - could not open socket

Tags: php, sockets, recaptcha

I am running Google recaptcha on my site although when testing the web form I get the error "Could not open socket".

I have researched the issue and have changed the line in recaptchalib.php to `define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname("www.google.com"));`

It worked once but I now I get the same error.

Form is located here http://euroexpress.hk/

Answer (score 0):

Is your `/etc/resolv.conf` readable by php? I had this error on the last site I set up with recaptchpa and we had to chmod it to 644 and restart apache so php could read it.

Otherwise if that doesn't work, you can switch recaptcha to use curl, and that should do the trick.